# Rust-like comment compilation for kotlin/java?

Tags: kotlin, compilation, comments, code-documentation

in short, rust compiler can compile certain code in comments, such as example code, against the actual code - resulting in always up to date commentary.

Anyone aware of any sort-of-equivalent for Kotlin or Java Code?
Any suggestions?

Had a hard time googling for it.

What i long for is basically:

````kotlin
/**
 * some descriptive text
 * 
 * Example:
 * ```
 * val foo = bar();
 * assert(foo == "bar"); 
 * ```
 *
 * @return "bar" as String
**/
fun bar() = "bar";
````

the example, just like an automated test, should fail when bar changes its return value. otherwise become a part of the documentation as sample code.

Comment: Is what you're describing different than what's explained here? https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-02-publishing-to-crates-io.html

Comment: actually its the very same - except that i need this for kotlin ;)

Comment: It's called [KDoc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kotlin-doc.html) in Kotlin and Javadoc in Java.

Comment: @Tenfour04 but `javadoc` can't compile and run the example code nested inside Javadoc comments. See https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-02-publishing-to-crates-io.html#documentation-comments-as-tests

Comment: Not quite the same thing, but another place to put sample code is in automated tests — they're not compiled into the final code, but they _are_ compiled and run along with the build, and so are guaranteed to be up-to-date and work. And if well-written, they should explain how to use the code being tested. (You can use a framework such as [JUnit](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/jvm-test-using-junit.html); build automation tools such as [Maven](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/maven.html) and [Gradle](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html) can run them automatically as part of the build process.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach I just discovered would be to use the [KDoc `@sample` tag](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kotlin-doc.html#sample-identifier) to build associated sample code which would then be embedded in the Dokka-generated documentation.

I found [this article which elaborates on that approach](https://medium.com/@rfletcher_96265/testable-samples-in-kotlin-api-docs-f7cd2da17c4f) and also points out some drawbacks like sub-optimal rendering. But it's certainly a good start in that direction.

Comment: this is pretty awesome as it also generates a repl in dokka. ty Marcus